# How to swap two SyntaxNode (Roslyn C#)

Tags: c#, refactoring, roslyn

I'm currently writing a refactoring tool for visual studio 2015 and I'd like to create a refactoring which is reorder class elements. My problem: **I can't swap two SyntaxNode at the SyntaxTree**. The basic swap method does not work because SyntaxNode is a reference type, and the result is two copy of firstSyntaxNode after the execution of the code below.

```
SyntaxNode tmp = firstSyntaxNode;
root = root.ReplaceNode(firstSyntaxNode, secondSyntaxNode);
root = root.ReplaceNode(secondSyntaxNode, tmp);
```

**How can I swap two SyntaxNode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to replace both nodes at the same time by calling `ReplaceNodes`:

```
root = root.ReplaceNodes(new[] { firstSyntaxNode, secondSyntaxNode },
    (original, _) => original == firstSyntaxNode ? secondSyntaxNode : firstSyntaxNode);
```